# Цикл forEach. Обращение к элементу с index + 1

Tags: javascript

```
//Есть массив со всеми картинками на странице
let all_img = document.querySelectorAll('.task-12 img');

//есть кнопка:
document.querySelector('.prev').addEventListener('touchstart', function () {

  all_img.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (element.classList.contains('active-img')) {
      element.classList.remove('active-img');
      all_img[index + 1].classList.add('active-img');
    }
  });
```

Если я обращаюсь к элементу с индексом + 1 - ничего не работает. Если index - 1 - все ОК. В чем проблема? При чем, если вывести в консоль all_img[index + 1] я получу то, что мне нужно. Но класс к этому элементу я добавить не могу.

ошибка:

```
script.js:72 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
    at script.js:72
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script.js:66)
```

Comment: Нет. Длина массива равна кол-ву элементов массива. А индексы начинаются с нуля.

Comment: "если вывести в консоль all_img[index + 1] я получу то, что мне нужно." - нет, не получите.

Comment: @Igor Нет, получу. Я получаю в консоли элемент с индексом + 1; Но класс этому элементу я задать не могу.

Comment: Нет, не получаете. Он там остался от предыдущего касания. Вы можете создать в вопросе работающий пример, демонстрирующий проблему. Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" в редакторе вопроса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> если index + 1 изменить на index - 1 все работает.

Не думаю. Ни у одного элемента Вашего массива нет индексированных свойств. Так что до `classList` дело не доходит.

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3];

a.forEach((element, index) => {
  if (element == 2) {
    console.log(element[index - 1].classList);
  }
});
```

---

На последнем элементе Вы залезаете за границу массива.

```
if (index < all_img.length - 1)
  all_img[index + 1].classList.add('active-img');
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Вы мне очень помогли.

Comment: @forzeeh Пожалуйста. Заслуга - Ваша, так как Вы конструктивно отнеслись к замечаниям по качеству/содержанию вопроса. Желаю успехов.

Answer (score 4):

Допущено три ошибки:

1. Пренебрежение знанием о методе/типах

> //Есть массив со всеми картинками на странице
>   `let all_img = document.querySelectorAll('.task-12 img');`

`NodeList` это **не** массив. Различие типов важно понимать, чтобы не совершать более грубых ошибок в будущем.

2. Выход за диапазон коллекции нодов при обращении к ее элементам ([как уже ответил Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1044062/288409))

```js
all_img.forEach((element, index) => {
  // ...
  all_img[index + 1].classList.add('active-img');
  // ...
});
```

3. Алгоритмическая ошибка. Зачем каждому следующему элементу добавлять класс, а на *каждой* следующей итерации проверять его (класса) наличие, и удалять? Это лишено практической пользы.

Циклы часто являются "узким местом" во многих смыслах, поэтому хорошей привычкой будет всегда сокращать работу в итерациях до разумного минимума (делать только то, что действительно нужно сделать).
К сожалению, очень часто можно видеть как в циклах дублируются операции с DOM, напрасно инстанцируются объекты, множатся одинаковые функции листенеров событий. Сокращение подобной лишней работы - это не преоптимизация. Это повышение *качества* кода, и *четкости* его логики.

Решение может быть например таким:

```
for (var changed, i = all_img.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  all_img[i].classList.remove('active-img'); 
  if (!changed && i && all_img[i - 1].classList.contains('active-img')) {
    all_img[i].classList.add('active-img');
    changed = true; 
  }
}
```

Пишу с мобилы и без проверки, так что объясню логику (на тот случай если в коде и сам накосячил): перебирая элементы от конца к началу, мы у каждого текущего безусловно удаляем класс, и добавляем обратно только если ранее (за цикл) его не "переставляли вперед", и если предыдущий элемент есть (i > 0), и содержит класс.
Таким образом, одно лишнее действие за весь цикл - это ведь гораздо лучше, чем два лишних действия на каждой его итерации.
И мы яснее видим, в чем итоговые "намерения" этого участка кода, какую микрозадачу он решает.

*<sub>(предполагаю что читатель ответа автоматически понимает часть выражения `!changed && i` - при работе в команде с новичками, это можно развернуть на более императивный код с переменными. Еще лучше, когда такие вещи оформлены методами или хелпер-функциями, даже если не планируем их переиспользование)</sub>*

Comment: Вопрос о `forEach`, но этот метод неспособен перебирать в обратном порядке (чего требует задача, насколько я ее понял) - поэтому предлагаемое решение использует `for`.

Comment: `Алгоритмическая ошибка...Это лишено практического смысла.` - как по мне, лишено смысла каждый раз проходить весь объект эл-тов чтобы передвинуть "указатель"; и тут весь цикл это сплошное лишнее движение.

Comment: @InDevX, цикл является лишним усложнением **только если** классы не могут меняться другим кодом. К тому же, проблема из вопроса тесно связана с логикой циклов, и ответы без ее объяснения фактически являются оффтопом. Цель моего ответа прежде всего в том чтобы указать на общие повторяемые ошибки (особенно #3), а не в том чтобы решить единично-индивидуальную задачу ТСа.

Comment: Чтобы было понятнее, дополнил ответ раскрытием мысли о важности алгоритма применительно к циклам.

Answer (score 1):

> // т.е. forEach не видит элементы, по которым он еще не прошелся?

Он проходится по всем эл-там и всё видит.

У вас проблема в том что вы пытались к другому эл-ту массиву "достучаться" через текущий эл-т.

```js
let a = [1,2,3];

a.forEach((element, index) => {
 if(element == 2) {
  console.log(a[index + 1]);
 }
});
```

Зачем вам все картинки в массиве и циклом по ним проходиться? Можно как-то так это делать:

```js
document.querySelector('.prev').addEventListener('click', function (){
    let activeImg = document.querySelector('.task-12 img.active-img'),
        nextImg = activeImg.nextElementSibling,
        allImg = document.querySelectorAll('.task-12 img');
        
    if (allImg.length > getChildNumber(activeImg)+1) {
        activeImg.classList.remove('active-img');
        nextImg.classList.add('active-img'); 
    } else {
        activeImg.classList.remove('active-img');
        allImg[0].classList.add('active-img');
    }
    
});

function getChildNumber(element) {
  return Array.from(element.parentNode.children).indexOf(element);
}
```

```css
.task-12 img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.active-img {
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="task-12">
  <img class="active-img"  src="https://hsto.org/getpro/habr/post_images/c1a/e7e/e3d/c1ae7ee3d053f0809e9d22c320924a18.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://hsto.org/getpro/habr/post_images/c1a/e7e/e3d/c1ae7ee3d053f0809e9d22c320924a18.jpg" alt="">
  <img  src="https://hsto.org/getpro/habr/post_images/c1a/e7e/e3d/c1ae7ee3d053f0809e9d22c320924a18.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://hsto.org/getpro/habr/post_images/c1a/e7e/e3d/c1ae7ee3d053f0809e9d22c320924a18.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://hsto.org/getpro/habr/post_images/c1a/e7e/e3d/c1ae7ee3d053f0809e9d22c320924a18.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<button class="prev">next</button>
```

Comment: "априори" - ? *(2 символа нужно...)*

Comment: Так я о текущем forEach, а не о возможностях его

Comment: @InDevX "I don't think it means what you think it means."

Comment: @forzeeh в вопрос, все в вопрос

Comment: @Igor возможно, тут я вас, не совсем понял или совсем не понял, пока что не понял насколько я не понял

Comment: @forzeeh дополните вопрос, а ещё лучше добавьте воспроизводимый пример с "багом", или хотя бы сами напишите что не работает (что за ошибка?)

Comment: @InDevX Добавил ошибку

Comment: @forzeeh добавил ответ

Comment: @forzeeh ещё немного подправил. На ваш вопрос уже ответил **Igor**, вы прост выходили за допустимый индекс, что и давало undefined. Если по полочкам - через цикл вы перебираете все эл-ты, у текущего активного убираете клас и задаёте следующему, т.е. на следующей итерации текущий будет прошлым следующим (т.е. ему мы добавили клас), и опять у него забираете клас и даёте следующему, и так до конца массива. А на последнем эл-те массива вы класс задаёте уже несуществующему эл-ту, отсюда и undefined ошибка.

Comment: @InDevX Спасибо большое за подробные разъяснения. Теперь все понятно!

Comment: @Leks нет, не правильный, вам **forzeeh** правильно ответил